# Why is my for loop not transferring all list items to my dictionary (PYTHON)

Tags: python

**I have 3 lists: year, list1, list2.
I want to create a dictionary with {year1: list_item1, year2: list_item2, etc..}
My code:**

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list2 = [6,7,8,9,10]

years = []
for i in range(2018,2024):
    years.append(i)
    
predicted_change = {}
n = 0
while n < 6:
    for i in years:
        for t in list1:
            for e in list2:
                predicted_change[i] = t
                n += 1
    break

predicted_change
```

**Results:** {2018: 5, 2019: 5, 2020: 5, 2021: 5, 2022: 5, 2023: 5}

**Any ideas? I was looking for** {2018: 1, 2019: 2, 2020: 3, etc...}
**Thanks!**

Comment: Your code is overwriting values; _at one point in time_ `1`, `2` or `3` will be assigned as values, but on a later iteration they all get overwritten with `5`.

Comment: That's an algorithm problem, not a Python problem, so without knowing what the purpose or intent behind your algorithm is (aka what real-world problem you're trying to solve), it's hard to suggest a fix.

Comment: (I wonder if you want to iterate over `(list1, list2)` pairs? In that case you'd want to do something like `for t, e in zip(list1, list2)` instead of `for t in list1: for e in list2:`)

Comment: Why are you iterating over `list2` but not using it at all? What exactly are you trying to do? As an aside, you can directly create a list from `range` objects: `list(range(2018, 2024))`.

Answer (score 1):

```
predicted_change = {}

for counter, i in enumerate(range(2018, 2024), start=1):
    predicted_change[i] = i
    predicted_change[i] = counter

print(predicted_change)
```

output

```
{2018: 1, 2019: 2, 2020: 3, 2021: 4, 2022: 5, 2023: 6}
```

---

Use `enumerate()` to get a counter in a loop

```
languages = ['Python', 'C', 'C++', 'C#', 'Java']
```

#### Bad way

---

```
i = 0 #counter variable
for language in languages:
    print(i, language)
    i+=1
```

or

```
for i in range(len(languages)):
    print(i, languages[i])
```

#### Good Way

---

```
for i, language in enumerate(languages):
    print(i, language)
```

Comment: I would add a brief explaination or link for the enumerate function, but this is a working answer anyway. +1

Comment: I will update the answer to explain to you

Comment: I already know how does it work  I was asking for the OP. Anyway a good explaination is given here: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/enumerate

Answer (score 0):

You update entries in `predicted_values` dictionary at each iteration of list2 to the current value of t from list1. The final value for each key in predicted_values will always be the right-most value in list1:

```
while n < 6:
    for i in years:
        for t in list1:
            for e in list2:
                # When i = 2018 and t = 1, you assign predicted_change[2018] = 1 at each iteration of list2
                # When i = 2018 and t = 2, you assign predicted_change[2018] = 2 at each iteration of list2
                # ... and so on until t = 5, which results in predicted_change[2018] = 5. Same for when i = 2019, 2022, ...
                predicted_change[i] = t
                n += 1
```

I agree with the comments under your question:

1. Iterating over list2 is redundant given your code and what you're saying you're trying to do
2. If you're trying to create a dict where the number of keys (years in your example) == number of items in list1 and each year should map to a value from list1 consecutively, there are better ways to do it.

For example:

```
initial_year = 2018
for k, t in zip(range(initial_year, initial_year + len(list1)), list1):
    predicted_change[k] = t

# predicted_change: {2018: 1, 2019: 2, 2020: 3, 2021: 4, 2022: 5}
```

Hopefully it makes sense. Good luck with whatever you're trying to do!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to combine two lists into a dictionary, where one list provides the key and the other list is the value, you can just do this

```py
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
years = list(range(2018,2024))

predicted_change = {y:v for y,v in zip(years,list1)}

print(predicted_change)
```

which gives

```
{2018: 1, 2019: 2, 2020: 3, 2021: 4, 2022: 5}
```

*Note*: It is unclear in your example what the second list is supposed to do... If you were wanting to combine the entries from both lists, you could do something like this

```py
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list2 = [6,7,8,9,10]
years = list(range(2018,2024))

predicted_change = {y:[lv1, lv2] for y,lv1,lv2 in zip(years,list1,list2)}

print(predicted_change)
```

which creates a list of values for each "year" from the two lists

```
{2018: [1, 6], 2019: [2, 7], 2020: [3, 8], 2021: [4, 9], 2022: [5, 10]}
```